# Error show css masonry grid gallery on iMac

Tags: css, html, gallery, stylesheet, screen-resolution

Demo: [click here](http://carbondove.com/)

On chrome, safari on Macbook firefox, opera,... anything all ok
[image: google chrome]

But see below issue on the iMac
![image: imac error]

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into your code.

I see you use a WordPress template, try to clear your cache in safari.

Otherwise ask in WordPress section for more answers.

Comment: yes, I has been clear cache data, all browser ok, but with iMac desktop are error

Comment: Download other browser.